# Spring boot with embedded tomcat runs on a port but its won't work

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm so new in Linux and I'm trying to run my Spring boot application with embedded tomcat on it I tried literally everything on the internet but I can't understand my problem. So this is my code (Maven)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.my.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.test.my.Applocation.App</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and this is my application.properties file.

```
server.port=0
```

and this is how I build my project to Jar :

**mvn -> clean -> compile -> package**

and I can run this application on my Windows computer and its working just fine! but my problem is in the Linux server when I run this application with systemed this is the log and it says it was successful but it's not working

```
INFO 20351 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b190a49] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO 20351 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
INFO 20351 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
INFO 20351 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
INFO 20351 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
INFO 20351 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO 20351 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2302 ms
INFO 20351 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
INFO 20351 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 41940 (http) with context path ''
INFO 20351 --- [           main] c.t.c.TransApplication.TransApplication  : Started TransApplication in 4.878 seconds (JVM running for 5.402)
```

and this is my

> netstat -ltnpa | grep -i --colour LISTEN

log from **41940** port

```
tcp6       0      0 :::41940                :::*                    LISTEN      20351/java
```

but now i want to send a request to this port with **example.com:41940/myrequest** but its not working and server is not respondig

===================
EDIT
i edit the **server.port=0 to 8090**

and this is the result of

> curl -XGET localhost:8090
>
> curl -XGET localhost:8090   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average
>   Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:--     0100    93    0    93    0     0    325      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   326 {   "_links" : {
>       "profile" : {
>         "href" : "http://localhost:8090/profile"
>       }   } }

Comment: Have you already tried to set a static port like 8080?

Comment: my 8080 port is not available but I tried 8090 and it's not working either @HannesR

Comment: What does the log say when you set a static port?

Comment: What configuration do you have in place that will map example.com to the IP address of the server?

Comment: exactly like 41940  port, everything is up and running but it's not working @HannesR

Comment: @AndyWilkinson can you tell me how can i know that caus i buy this server and i did not configure it

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with your DNS. Try it locally with your IP. Or try it at first with curl and localhost to get something from the Webserver.

Comment: @HannesR I know I'm asking a lot but I'm really not familiar with Linux and curl I'm kinda a new Java guy can you help me to do that?

Comment: @ReaTeria You should have been given some information about the server’s public IP address and perhaps domain name when you bought it. If there’s no DNS entry pointing to the server, ypu’d Have to buy a domain and set up the necessary records.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson no I have a domain and DNS configured correctly I know that

Comment: What do you get when you start this in the console: curl -XGET 
 http://localhost:PORTNUMBER

Comment: @HannesR please check my update

Comment: @HannesR why my netstat is different on my 8090 port and on the 993 port?

Comment: @HannesR 8090 port : tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      3249/java

Comment: @HannesR 993 port : tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5172/dovecot

Comment: Because it seems that the tomcat is only listening on IPv6. Do you also have a listener "tcp" on the port 8090?

Comment: @HannesR no it's only on the tcp6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I said I'm so new in Linux And the problem was that I did not introduce the port to the firewall and now working

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your application with this parameters:

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses`

And then with netstat make sure that the application is listening on IPv4.

If it is also not working post the output of this:

```
curl -sSL -D - http://localhost:8090 -o /dev/null
```

Have a look here: [Spring boot application listens over IPv6 without -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true and -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718174/spring-boot-application-listens-over-ipv6-without-djava-net-preferipv4stack-tru)

I think your tomcat only listens on IPv6 not IPv4.

BR

Comment: hi i tried to running with ipv6 and i couldn't but my problem solved thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am deploying my Spring Boot application to a Pivotal Cloud Foundation container.
I got the same error but found I was missing a POM dependency (and it appears you are too):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I found this in Post:
[Spring boot: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579432/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embedded-tomcat-servlet-container)

NOTE, it has led to different error for me, but I made progress.

Conclusion of *my* matter for posterity ...

I add this comment because this is what fixed my problem.

The Dependency was pulling in Servlet API 2.5
Tomcat 8.5 (embedded Spring Boot) needs Servlet API 3.1!

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
```

Dependency had Servlet 2.5 API.
 Tomcat 8.1 needs '3.1'

found to looking at Maven dependency tree:

```
man dependency:tree
```

From this post:  [Getting NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername)

Comment: in the spring starter web dependency there is an embedded tomcat

Comment: I add this comment because this is what fixed my problem.

The Dependency was pulling in Servlet API 2.5
Tomcat 8.5 (embedded Spring Boot) needs Servlet API 3.1!

<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
<version>1.9</version>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
</exclusion>

Dependency had Servlet 2.5 API.
 Tomcat 8.1 needs '3.1'

From this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername